# Testing an android app

Tags: android, testing

I am creating an android app. I have one device that I am testing it on and I have looked at the Eclipse screen and emulators. However, I have read that the emulators are not always accurate. I was wondering if someone had an idea of what I should do in order to test my app better? Is there a place/store I could go that may let me test my app on various Android devices? What steps should I take for the process of testing before publishing it on the market?

Comment: `I have read that the emulators are not always accurate`.  Exactly where did you read this?  Of course you should test on real devices but only because the SDK emulators are *more* accurate and do not contain the device specific hacks made by the OEMs.

Comment: Are you suggesting that if the app works on the all 10 or so predetermined emulators that Eclipse offers, then I shouldn't worry about testing it on a bunch of real devices? I'm sorry I'm new to app development and am just trying to create a product to put eventually on the market. what suggestions do you have as far as testing is concerned in terms of different screen sizes and such issues?

Comment: Someday I heard about a open testing group on which you can send your apps before it's release. Don't remember where.

Comment: The predetermined emulators only vary in hardware, resolution etc. What's more important are the differences in the SDK versions. The most common problems are "it runs fine on 4.1 but not on 4.2" and "it only happens on Galaxy S2". The former because something changed in the API, the latter usually because Samsung changed something typically in the framework which breaks apps. If your app is OK on your target API levels, and you've tested on as many real devices as you can, you've done the job. I've got an app that only crashed on an HTC Desire in French. I fixed it, but still don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test on different real and virtual devices there are different online tools that you could use. Some of them are on the market since long time, some of them are pretty new, some of them are free, some are not. Just to name a few: PerfectoMobile, TestObject, DeviceAnywhere.
In my company we use [TestObject](http://testobject.com) and we know the guys working at there pretty good. They do a really nice job for a really competitive price, so I highly recommend them. They offer hundreds of virtual and real devices, that you can remotely control from your computer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no better way to test your app that on multiple real devices.

One of the top reasons for me is that you can easily simulate different situations under which your app should normally function: turning screen, receiving a call/sms while doing some operations, harassing the UI and the whole app with user interaction to see how it behaves.

Different phones have different hardware capabilities, i had issues with app permissions that it limited the number of phones that could use my app and figured a way to remove it and still keep the same functionality now on a larger user base.  I only figured this out by testing on multiple phones.

Screen densities and sizes you can test on the emulator but you should still test it on a few different phones to see how it actually behaves on ldpi,hdpi,mdpi...especially if you are using images in your app.----the emulator showed that everything is perfect, but once i installed on phones it turned out the other way...

The best way to test the app is to put it on a few real devices and let other people test your app for some period. Since you developed it you will remember to test only certain things you think are important.

People that have nothing with android programming will simulate real users and will find others bugs that wouldn't occur to you. Also keep in mind that some bugs show up occasionally in special situations, so its good that you publish your app for your testers, since then they can send you crash reports through google play, and this will help you alot to improve your app.

This is my personal opinion from my own experience. I personally would have enough nerves to sit all day in front of a computer and test the app in low responsive emulator :)

Edit 1:
 Developer console also has the option for beta and alpha testing, you can check that out.

Comment: How would you suggest getting a hold of these devices?

Comment: If you are not working alone, but with some developers each of you should have an android phone. Its a must for a developer. When i started developing i would use my friends,friends of friends, family's phones for testing. You do the main development on your phone and colleagues phones, but use everyone you know for testing.  >>>>>>> Dont worry you dont need 100 different phones, but if you can get a hold of 7,8 different phones(different android versions on some) thats enough to cover a big % .  And always keep in mind that you can cover everything, the real test starts with publishing.

Comment: Also all the big apps have bugs, gtalk, gmail, firefox, opera, they all crash sometimes on my phone so developing an app doesnt stop once you publish it, thats when you start enhancing it.

Answer (score 0):

It's true that emulators are not the same as phones, but then again in my experience, phones are all different from each other too :[

I find that besides being slow, emulators usually do a good job. It depends on what you're doing. Media record/playback development should be done on a phone.

That being said, it doesn't hurt to test on a real phone, starting with the Google Nexus devices, because they are the most standard.

If you don't want to pay for a phone, then put your apk in Dropbox or email attachment, visit the local phone store, install the apk and test. Don't forget to logout of Dropbox or email.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout [Nativetap](http://nativetap.io) which allows you to remotely test your application on many devices remotely as if it was in your hand, with multitouch gesture support, performance profiling, screenshots, session recording, etc. Nativetap allows you to test on some of the latest devices like S8/S8+, LG G6, etc. in their physical UI.

In many ways Nativetap bridges that gap between emulators and physical devices, because you actually are testing a physical device while remote.

DISCLOSURE: I work with Nativetap.